# ORA-03111 error when i use date in querystring

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I have a simple query string. I'm getting a weird database error when i use datetime in querystring and can't figure out why. Query works on oracle without error.

```
    Dim selectedDate As String = (Today.AddDays(-2000)).ToString("d-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")).ToUpper()
    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand
    cmd.Connection = xConnection
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ORDER_DETAIL WHERE ORDER_TYPE='PO' AND STATUS<>'CANCEL' AND PN='XXXXXX' AND LAST_DATE_RECEIVED>TO_DATE('27-JUN-2013','DD/mm/YYYY')"
    Dim dr1 As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

I think it's not related Oracle server or provider because it doesn't give an error if i remove the date part. Do you have any idea?

Exception details below:

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=ORA-03111: Break received on communication channel
  Source=Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver
  StackTrace:
   at OracleInternal.TTC.TTCExecuteSql.ReceiveExecuteResponse(Accessor[]& defineAccessors, Accessor[] bindAccessors, Boolean bHasReturningParams, SQLMetaData& sqlMetaData, SqlStatementType statementType, Int64 noOfRowsFetchedLastTime, Int32 noOfRowsToFetch, Int32& noOfRowsFetched, Int64& queryId, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 initialLOBFetchSize, Int64[] scnFromExecution, Boolean bAllInputBinds, Int32 arrayBindCount, DataUnmarshaller& dataUnmarshaller, MarshalBindParameterValueHelper& marshalBindParamsHelper, Int64[]& rowsAffectedByArrayBind, Boolean bDefineDone, Boolean& bMoreThanOneRowAffectedByDmlWithRetClause, List`1& implicitRSList, Boolean bLOBArrayFetchRequired)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[] scnForExecution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64& internalInitialLOBFS, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection, OracleLogicalTransaction& oracleLogicalTransaction, IEnumerable`1 adrianParsedStmt, Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at VB_TestApp.Module1.Main() in c:\users\.....

Inner Exception 1:
NetworkException: ORA-03111: Break received on communication channel
```

Comment: Can you include the exact error you are seeing?

Comment: This looks like VB.NET

Comment: @TinMan Sorry and thank you. I edited the tag.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for answering,  exact error like this:
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=ORA-03111: Break received on communication channel
  Source=Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver
  StackTrace: ...

Comment: This sounds like a database driver error.  Why do you think datetime has something to do with the error?

Comment: Could you share Oracle DB and ODP.Net version?

Comment: @hkutluay Oracle Database Version:
11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
and odp version is 18.3.0

Comment: `TO_DATE('27-JUN-2013','DD/mm/YYYY')` should be `TO_DATE('27-JUN-2013','dd-mon-yyyy')`

Comment: @SudiptaMondal thank you for your reply but i tried various date format, it works on oracle but gives the same error with ExecuteReader

Comment: can you downgrade odp.net to Version 12.2.0.1?

Comment: @Ozitron can you check if it works fine for `last_date_received > sysdate` ?

Comment: @SudiptaMondal works fine with sysdate

Comment: @Ozitron maybe you can try with a standard syntax. `last_date_received > date '2013-06-27'`  "date 'yyyy-mm-dd'" is also another way of passing date.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal thank you so much for help, you've solved the problem. 
I was trying the `'dd-mon-yyyy'` format obsessively cuz i see the result from db like `23-OCT-13`. Using standart syntax worked fine. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ozitron - Cool, I have added this as an answer.

Comment: @hkutluay i tried to downgrade version but it's not worked because problem was much simplier than that. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below syntax needs to be changed slightly. The syntax in the question has a date format syntax error.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ORDER_DETAIL WHERE ORDER_TYPE='PO' AND STATUS<>'CANCEL' AND PN='XXXXXX' AND LAST_DATE_RECEIVED>TO_DATE('27-JUN-2013','DD/mm/YYYY')"
```

can be changed to standard syntax

```
AND LAST_DATE_RECEIVED> date '2013-06-27'"
```

Oracle Supports ANSI date format - [Standard Docs Link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062)

Comment: Thank you so much for help, you've solved the problem. I was trying the `'dd-mon-yyyy'` format obsessively. Standard syntax is working fine.

Comment: @Ozitron - I would like to think that your earlier syntax should work as well, unless you are missing out on something obvious but not easily found :)